# Insert within FORALL loop in PL/SQL

Tags: performance, plsql, forall

Is it possible to do something like this in pl/sql for bulk insert using `FORALL`?

```
TYPE c_type1 IS RECORD
(
column1 table1.column1%TYPE,
column2 table1.column2%TYPE,
client table2.client%TYPE
);
type1 c_type1;

CURSOR cur_t IS  select * BULK COLLECT INTO recs from table3 ;

begin
  FOR recs IN cur_t
  LOOP

  SELECT * INTO type1 FROM  (select a.column1, a.column2,imm.client 
  ...
    from table1 a, table2 imm        
   WHERE 
    a.column1 = recs.column1
  ) WHERE ROWNUM=1;

  INSERT INTO table2 values (recs.column1,type1.column2);

  ...
```

P.S : There are more 80 columns to be inserted.

Comment: You can use forall in this way. http://psoug.org/snippet/FORALL-Insert_499.htm

Comment: @XING if you notice ..INSERT INTO table2 values (recs.column1,type1.column2); I have to insert records from two tables .

Comment: Whats table 3 use..Why r u running the loop. Question is not clear..Table naming is not proper

Comment: A cursor declaration doesn't have any `into` clause, and the `recs` array isn't declared anywhere, although there is a `recs` record implicitly declared by the cursor FOR loop. I can't really make head or tail of it.

Comment: Try harder to format your questions. They must make sense to us. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking your next question.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not pretty clear but looking at your code I have the following. Check if this is what you were looking for.

```
declare

CURSOR cur_t IS  
                select t3.column1 , t1.column2
                from table3 t3
                inner join table1 t1
                on t3.column1 = t1.column1;

type var_cur is table of cur_t%rowtype;

var var_cur;

begin

open cur_t;

  LOOP

    FETCH cur_t bulk collect into var limit 100;       
     EXIT WHEN cur_t%NOTFOUND;

     FORALL i IN 1 .. var.count SAVE EXCEPTIONS
      INSERT INTO TABLE2 
     VALUES var(i);         

    END LOOP;

  CLOSE distinctUserIdCursor;

COMMIT;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('Error in Insertion of record' || '~~~~' || SQLERRM);
      FOR indx IN 1 .. SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS.COUNT
         LOOP
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS (indx).ERROR_INDEX|| ': '
               || SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS (indx).ERROR_CODE);
      END LOOP;

end;
```

Comment: for each matching record of recs in type1 ..there should be only 1 record ..inner join might create 2 entries **a.column1 = recs.column1
) WHERE ROWNUM=1;**

Comment: Okay..take the skeleton of my code and implement your logic. I hope it should work. I explained how to use forall.